# Python email.parser in development

Tags: python, email

Whats the best way to play with the email.parser package in Python?  I have an externally hosted webserver that I can send emails too, but this development process is very tedious and I feel like there should be something I can do locally.

Anyone have any suggestions?

## EDIT

I want to be able to pull image attachments from emails, and the only way it seems I can test this is to write some code, put it up on my webserver, send myself some email, and then check what happened. I was hoping to mimic this process, locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to do exactly? What are you using the server for currently?

You can use `email.parser.FeedParser.feed(...)` to pass in an email from a string. So you can just store some emails locally and feed them in that way:

```
import email.parser
parser = email.parser.FeedParser()

email = '''\
From: Steve <steve@steve.steve>
To: Someone <someone@foo.com>
Subject: Hey what's up

This is a dummy email, no server involved.
'''

parser.feed(email)
msg = parser.close()

print "To:", msg['to']
print "From:", msg['from']
print "Subject:", msg['subject']
print "Body:", repr(msg.get_payload())
```

Output:

```
$ python x.py
To: Someone <someone@foo.com>
From: Steve <steve@steve.steve>
Subject: Hey what's up
Body: 'This is a dummy email, no server involved.\n'
```

---

**Edit**: In response to your comment about extracting attachments (e.g. images), email attachments follow the [MIME standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). You can either copy a raw email (depends on which client and server you use), or build your own by hand following the standard.

Here's an example of an email with a PNG file attached:

```
import email.parser
parser = email.parser.FeedParser()

email = '''\
From: Steve <steve@steve.steve>
To: Someone <someone@foo.com>
Subject: Hey what's up
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=_boundary

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.

--_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the body of the message. No mail server involved.

--_boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.png;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--_boundary--
'''

parser.feed(email)
msg = parser.close()

print "To:", msg['to']
print "From:", msg['from']
print "Subject:", msg['subject']
print "Body:", repr(msg.get_payload())
print ""

for payload in msg.get_payload():
    filename = payload.get_filename()
    if filename:
        print "Got an attachment: %r" % filename,
        print "that is %r bytes long." % len(payload.get_payload().decode('base64'))
    else:
        print "Got a message: %r" % payload.get_payload()
```

And when I write that file to disk, it is a valid PNG file:

```
$ python -i x.py
>>> open('x.png', 'wb').write(payload.get_payload().decode('base64'))

$ file x.png
x.png: PNG image data, 16 x 16, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but what about testing extracting an image from an attachment?

Comment: Attachments are sent using the MIME standard. I've added an example to my answer.